# Unable to see Security Token Service under Manage WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am unable to see Security Token Service under Manage on WSO2 IS 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure STS as follows, after adding a Service Provider in Main menu
[image]

Thanks,
Pushpalanka